# Unit Testing complex Observable flows

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable, ngrx

I have the following function, which (I think) returns a compound observable:

```
test(cell) {
   const observ1 = this.store.select('range').flatMap((val: IRange) => {return this.getCellOEE(val.value)});
   const observ2 = this.getCellOEE(cell);
   return Observable.merge(observ1, observ2);
}
```

I am using this in an angular 4 service, and trying to unit test with jasmine and karma.

So I am mocking store like this:

```
class mockStore {
  select(): Observable<IRange> {
    return Observable.of({value: 'daily', start: moment(), end: moment()}, {value: 'monthly', start: moment(), end: moment()})
  }
}
```

and then I have the following test:

```
 it('should update result on store change', fakeAsync(inject(
    [MockBackend, OeeService],
    (backend: MockBackend, s: OeeService) => {
      const urls = [];

      backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        const req: any = connection.request;
        urls.push(req.url);
        if (req.method === RequestMethod.Get && req.url === 'api/getLine/data' req.headers.get('range') === 'daily') {
          connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: { data: 12 } })));
        }
        if (req.method === RequestMethod.Get && req.url === 'api/getLine/data' &&
          req.headers.get('range') === 'monthly') {
          connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: { data: 15 } })));
        }
      });
      let value;
      s.test('powders').subscribe(val => {
        value = val;
      })

      tick();
      expect(value).toEqual(12);
      tick();
      expect(value).toEqual(15);
    })
  ));
```

I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve, so when the `test()` function is initially called, a straight forward http call is made, but then my mocked store should release a change in params, map that to an http request with the new params and then return a different value.

I currently get the first `expect()` passing, but the second failing with:

> Expected 12 to contain 15

So I think there is a timing issue? Any ideas how I can resolve this? I think the test is important to verify, because then I can sue some good old TDD to prove whether this approach works.

## Update:

Here is my full unit test [file](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/82f28ae77e2323e82028f3dedf82bd2f)

Comment: I think you may want `switchMap`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for the suggestion, Where would I use that?

Comment: where mockStore is used?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova an instance of it is provided the the component instead of @ngtx/Store

Comment: hmm, mock should be used in test for mocking store and component should use a normal ngrx store

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Yes, that is what I am doing

Comment: can u please show the whole test where you are use mockStore as a provider. I feel like we can't help you becuase we do not see the whole test.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova I have added a link to a gist in the question

Comment: Can you add `getCellOEE` implementation?

Comment: @yurzui Sure, but it is just an angular http observable

Comment: Please correct this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/eIH38IlZ6VyvFF2TRJK6?p=preview.

Comment: Not sure why tick does not work. but this works:       let values=[];
      s.test('powders').subscribe(val => {
        values.push(val);
      })

      expect(values[0]).toEqual(12);
     
      expect(values[1]).toEqual(15);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there is a timing issue with the test. By the time the first  `Expect()` expression occurs, both mock `Responses` have returned. To fix your test, you can change one of the responses to use `setTimeout()` and set the `tick()` between expect clauses to some time after that delay.

eg:

```
if (req.method === RequestMethod.Get && req.url === 'api/getLine/data' && req.headers.get('range') === 'monthly') {
    setTimeout(() => { 
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: { data: 15 } })));      }, 100);
}
```

and:

```
expect(value).toEqual(12);
tick(100);
expect(value).toEqual(15);
```

However, similarly to what julia said above, a better test would be to push the values into an array and check that the values at the respective indexes are correct. In this case I would recommend replacing `flatMap()` in your test function with `concatMap()`, which preserves order. You can then write multiple tests with each response delayed and still check that the values at the respective indexes are correct:

```
tick(100);
expect(values[0]).toEqual(12);
expect(values[1]).toEqual(15);
```

Comment: Thx! I read first time and I couldn't get the idea. Now I did